# Silverlight, when rotating textbox not all the text shows

Tags: c#, silverlight, layout, textbox, rotatetransform

I have a custom control an inside of it I have a textbox that rotates depending wether you'd like it to collapse or expand, when it is collapsed I want the textbox to be vertical and when it is expanded I want it horizontal.

The problem is that when it is vertical the textbox doesn't show all the text, I've being looking for an answer, and I understand it has to do with the way silverlight updates it's layout. Here is my code

```
private void CollapseControl()
{
    CollapseCommand.Content = "E";            
    CollapseCommand.Margin = _btnMarginOnCollapse;

    BtnZoomIn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    BtnZoomOut.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    ScrollViewerStackPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    ZoomPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    this.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    this.Width = 40;

    RotateTransform nameRotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
    nameRotateTransform.Angle = 270;            
    Nametb.RenderTransform = nameRotateTransform;            
    Nametb.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
    Nametb.Height = Nametb.Width;
    Nametb.Width = Nametb.Height;
    Nametb.UpdateLayout();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to use the `LayoutTransformer` control from the [Silverlight toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/43528).

You wrap the existing textblock inside a `LayoutTransformer`

```
        <toolkit:LayoutTransformer x:Name="Namelt" ...>
            <toolkit:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform />
            </toolkit:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Nametb" Text="Hello World" />
        </toolkit:LayoutTransformer>
```

Then your code looks like:-

```
((RotateTransform)Namelt.LayoutTransform).Angle = 270;                         
Namelt.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;     
Namelt.Height = Nametb.Width;     
Namelt.Width = Nametb.Height;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just recently ran into a similar problem, and came up with the following solution (based on [a post on the Silverlight forums](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/198884/632141.aspx/1?p=True&t=634685508491785104)), which should help with your issue, too:

```
private void CollapseControl()
{
    CollapseCommand.Content = "E";
    CollapseCommand.Margin = _btnMarginOnCollapse;

    BtnZoomIn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    BtnZoomOut.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    ScrollViewerStackPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    ZoomPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    this.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;

    LayoutTransform lt = new LayoutTransform();
    lt.Content = Nametb;

    RotateTransform nameRotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
    nameRotateTransform.Angle = 270;

    lt.LayoutTransform = nameRotateTransform;
    lt.ApplyLayoutTransform();
    Nametb.UpdateLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just written following and my similar problem is solved.

```
layoutTransform.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
layoutTransform.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
```